# URL stored in weird format?

Tags: php, mysql

in my mysql column varchar(266), my data is being stored like this

www.torcache.(hash)

(hash continued)

.torrent

and this is sending back the error Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected.

How do i store the url in one line

here is the code that is updating the database

```
$sql_select = "UPDATE `database1`.`media` SET `media_url` =('" . $url . "') WHERE media_type= '4' AND media_url LIKE '%".$fname."%' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

A database will not randomly insert line breaks behind your back. What you put into it is what you should be getting out, so look at that `$url` **BEFORE** you run the query. And don't look at it in a web-based view. Remember that browsers treat linebreak charactes as spaces so you won't see if there's any breaks in there unless you view the page source, run the text through nl2br(), output it inside a `<pre>` block, etc...